# Eslint warrnings dont allow me to push to repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have two problems:

1) i can not push to our team repo since I have warrnings in my code and eslint react when I try to push.

2) That i actally get these warrnings in my local enviorment which noone else in the team does.

The thing is that I am the only one in the team that is getting the erros when trying to push.

What I have done:

installed a older version of eslint (5.16.0) -- nothing changed.

Tried to modify the warrnings in code:

a warrning regarding code that is not used:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  {
    const [view, setView] = useState('SignUp') // error here saying view is declared but not used.

    /*
    const VIEW_STATES: {[key: string]: string}  = {
      SignUp: <SignUp />,
      Success: <SuccessView />,
      Error: <ErrorView />,
    }
*/
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <main className="opt-main opt--bg-sm">
          <div className="-container">
            <div className="-row">
              <div className="-offset-sm-2 -col-sm-8 -offset-md-3 -col-md-6">
                <div className="opt--container">
                  <SignUp />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

When removing the above unused code then I get:

"Nested block is redundant"...

Again this is only happening on my pc. Colleagues do not have that problem and Im stuck right now and can not push my changes.

also tried:

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "rules": {
    "Handling warnings": {
      "quiet": true,
      "max-warnings": -10
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: `view` and `setView` are not being used in the code you've posted

Comment: u can disable Eslint for your urgent situation, but it's not recommended, u should remove or comment code that u didn't use here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours on this and after posting a noticed that someone had installed husky in our enviorment.

Since eslint was showing the error i thought it was the problem.

Uninstalled husky and all the problems vent with it.

Would remove the question if could since it is missleading in this case. 
Hopefully someone might stubble upon this.

Answer (score 2):

> view is declared but not used

That seems to be true: you should either use it, or remove it, that's the right way to go. You did mentioned you tried that, and then hit:

> "Nested block is redundant"

This is due to an extra outer pair of `{ }` braces. The end of your first line contains a `() => {`, but then the next line also starts with `{`, unnecessarily. Remove the extra `{` and final `}`, and it should work ok.

Comment: Adding to Tim's correct answer. Use <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> instead of  <></> per the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I wasa trying to point out that I am the only one having this issue. This is just one example that is not letting me push. Other collegues with same settings dont have this issue. Modifying multiple files at this stage is something we wont do since It is continously changning. I am looking to find a way to fix my enviorment to match the others.

Comment: I see @CodingLittle: that's not clear from the question or title, and you haven't provided any detail on the ESLint setup. What version of ESLint are you using, what config, and how are you and your colleagues running it? The output from running eslint with `--debug` added might have some clues too.

Comment: Was looking into my packages and apperently we were using husky which created these issues for me. I thought that this was an eslint issue since eslint was the one showing the issues. I uninstalled husky and my problems vent with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable eslint rules on a single line with the following comment:

```
const mycode = {..} // eslint-disble line
```